# what's the difference between git merge master vs git merge master coins

Tags: git, github

Suppose I'm checked out at coins branch and i run this command what's the difference. When can there be a difference. I am new to git, so exploring document confused me even more.

i want to know difference between the effect of

`git merge master`

vs

`git merge master coins`

Comment: from experimentation i see no difference. But that makes not that much sense. If i run this command in master it acts if i've ran `git merge coins` instead...if i run this in coins branch it works as if i've written `git merge master`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the first will merge the branch `master` into your branch and the second will attempt to merge both `master` and the branch `coins` into your branch.

[From the manual:](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html)

> `<commit>...`
>
> Commits, usually other branch heads, to merge into our branch. Specifying more than one commit will create a merge with more
>   than two parents (affectionately called an Octopus merge).
>
> If no commit is given from the command line, and if merge.defaultToUpstream configuration variable is set, merge the
>   remote-tracking branches that the current branch is configured to use
>   as its upstream. See also the configuration section of this manual page.

Since you are already on the branch `coins`, it will have as far as git is concerned already be merged in.  So the end result would be just merging in master.  But if you were on a different branch, it would merge all three (master, coins, and the branch you are on).

Comment: this goes well with what i got from experimentation